# "ための x ために" in this phrases

Tags: grammar, word-choice, syntax

I want to write "Happy anniversary for my beloved grandmother" in Japanese, colloquially. But, I don't know if I need to write

> 私の最愛の祖母の**ために**幸せな記念日

or

> 私の最愛の祖母の**ための**幸せな記念日

What the difference between `ために` and `ための`? Are both phrases correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 私の最愛の祖母のため**に**幸せな記念日
>
> 私の最愛の祖母のため**の**幸せな記念日

ために is adverbial and ための is adjectival. So grammatically speaking you use ための here so that 私の最愛の祖母のための can modify the noun phrase 幸せな記念日. But... as you say you want to write it **colloquially** (since your attempt is quite stiff... and actually it doesn't really sound like wishing her a happy anniversary), how about...

> 「[大好]{だいす}きなおばあちゃんへ　[記念日]{きねんび}おめでとう！」
> or
> 「大好きなおばあちゃん　記念日おめでとう！」

If it's her wedding anniversary, you can just replace 記念日 with [結婚]{けっこん}[記念日]{きねんび}.

Comment: Hee they say き is a particle? OMG they're giving wrong furigana too! It's not [大好]{おおよし}き but [大好]{だいす}き. 大好き(+だ,な,etc) is a na-adjective.

Comment: Yes. Sorry (I deleted my comment). Maybe Jisho can't work very well with coloquial phrase.

Answer (score 2):

> "Happy anniversary for my beloved grandmother" in Japanese, colloquially.
>
> 私の最愛の祖母のために幸せな記念日
> 私の最愛の祖母のための幸せな記念日

The latter with の makes it a perfect noun phrase.
The former with に feels like not completed.

How are you going to use it? If it's a message on a card to give your grandmother, the former would work by adding を at the end of it, sounding like wishing for a good anniversary, and you can also cheer it up with an exclamation mark. It'll make a beautiful message. :)

Comment: なんか機械翻訳っぽいなーと思ったら、グーグル翻訳だったようですな・・・→ 　https://translate.google.co.jp/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#auto/ja/Happy%20anniversary%20for%20my%20beloved%20grandmother　「私の最愛の祖母のための幸せな記念日」ってそのまんま

Comment: That is amazingly well done for Google translator.

Comment: へー てことはあなたに翻訳をお願いしたらきっとこういう日本語になるわけですねーw

Comment: フラグさせていただきました。今後、気をつけて発言してください。

Comment: 「私の最愛の祖母のために幸せな記念日を！」　重厚なひびきを持った立派なメッセージだと思います。しかし、おばあちゃんには少しだけ重厚すぎる気がします。

Comment: What is the point of rewriting a whole private message? Will someone be happy when given a message written by total stranger? I find it'll be better even the translation made by a machine because that is the one that the OP got it first hand. I've told the OP some relative grammar points that I can think of.

Comment: Well, yes. I used Google Translator. I always revise to find errors, but is hard when to want colloquial phrases =P